# Is there a way to get access to the row height previously calculated in "heightForRowAtIndexPath"?

Tags: uitableview, height

I calculate the height of a row in the method "heightForRowAtIndexPath" but I need to use this value   in the method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" ... is there a way to get access to the value already calculated or do I need to do the calculations again ?

Thks,

Gotye.

Comment: Can't you memoize the result in an ivar?

Comment: Well, why wasting memory and time if the system is already saving the ivar for me ? I just want to know if there is something like [indexpath height] ?!?